# Why won't a friend show up under a game tab?

Tags: steam

On Steam, every friend who plays a game that you have will appear under a "Friends" section on the games page. But, I have a friend who plays the same game as me (I can see them on my friends list, and it says they are in the game in question) but they do not show up under the friends tab on the game in my library. Why is this?

Comment: Could it be that one of you only recently bought the game? I had the same issue a while back. Me and my friend had just purchased a game, and it took a while for Steam to 'catch up'.

Comment: They could also be playing the game through Family Sharing - they do not own the game in question, but are able to play it nonetheless.

Comment: It's possible to hide a particular game from showing up in the tab, check your Friends settings.

Comment: Some games have been 'redeployed', the name and icon may be the same, but the actual item in your libraries may differ. Though this doesn't happen anymore and is quite rare. Could you tell what game it is?

Comment: @Mixxiphoid It is specific to this person, regardless of game. Some games in question though would be Team Fortress 2 and Tom Clancy Ghost Recon Wildlands.

Comment: @Shadow Z. And you are sure they *own* those games?

Comment: @Joachim Yeah, I have played said games with them.

Comment: Yes, but that does not necessarily mean they own them, hence the question: they could be playing using someone else's library. Or they blocked their visibility, like Little Helper suggested.